# SQLGrammarException for a table with embeddable primary key

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I created 2 tables, **Bank** and **Branches**.

I created the DAO/BO classes and interfaces for both POJO.

I mapped them using Annotations.

I'm using Hibernate and Spring.

I tested a `findAll` method on the **Bank** table...

```
public List<Bank> findAll() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Bank");
}
```

...and it was successful.

The **id** of **Bank** table, consists - alongside the **id** of **Branch** table - the primary key of the **Branch** table.

So I made an `Embeddable` class :

```
@Embeddable
public class BranchPK implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8721469933759558600L;
    private Integer brchNum;
    private Integer bankNum;

    public BranchPK() {

    }
    @Column(name="BRCHNUM", precision=3, scale=0)
    public Integer getBrchNum() {
        return this.brchNum;
    }
    @Column(name="BANKNUM", precision=3, scale=0)
    public Integer getBankNum() {
        return this.bankNum;
    }

    public void setBrchNum(Integer brchNum) {
        this.brchNum = brchNum;
    }


    public void setBankNum(Integer bankNum) {
        this.bankNum = bankNum;
    }


}
```

The **Branch** table is represented like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="BRANCH")
public class Branch implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9075916046034338274L;
    @EmbeddedId
    private BranchPK primaryKey;
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="BANKNUM")
    private Bank bank;
.........
```

Everything seems good and in order, but when I repeat the previous `findAll` method to fetch all branches

```
public List<Branch> findAll() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Branch");
}
```

I received this error:

> could not execute query; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

**Update**

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.612 sec <<< FAILURE!
testFinddAll(bdl.cdr.core.BankBankDAOTest)  Time elapsed: 0.19 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:630)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:913)
    at bdl.cdr.core.dao.impl.BankBranchDAOImpl.findAll(BankBranchDAOImpl.java:14)
    at bdl.cdr.core.bo.impl.BankBranchBOImpl.findAll(BankBranchBOImpl.java:19)
    at bdl.cdr.core.BankBankDAOTest.testFinddAll(BankBankDAOTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:930)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'bankbranch0_.T_BANKNUM' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2313)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete stack trace? text above the exception also

Comment: @Zeus check the update please (You will notice that some classes have different names, I made the above example to clarify things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error shows `Unknown column 'bankbranch0_.T_BANKNUM' in 'field list'` try to find if the table has the T_BANKNUM column in the table. It will not be there, remove it from the mapping pojo.

Comment: THAAAAAAAAAAAANKS! :D It's named `F_BANKNUM` so I mistyped it! I have to learn how to read exceptions.